# How to alter between to different fields with a checkbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing a windows form in C# and there is a checkbox called "electronic delivery". Under it is a field for "email address". Now I would like to add the option that the email field is only visible if checkbox is checked.
If checkbox is not checked, I would like to have a different field there.
I know how to handle this on the code side, to make things visible/hidden, but how do I place the fields in the form? Should I place one on top of another? Then I won't be able to access the one below to change it's properties. 
Or should I keep only one filed and change it's name inside the code?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.controlcollection?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: So I can put only one field in the form, and then hide it and create a new one from inside the code and after that alter between them with visibility?

Comment: Pretty much.  You can add the controls at design time (using the designer) and then at run time toggle their visibility but that may  make your form look messy when viewed in the designer since you have controls on top of one another. The ControlCollection allows you to dynamically do the same thing via code and may be the neater solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your controls in FlowLayoutPanel control. The FlowLayoutPanel control arranges its contents dynamically in a horizontal or vertical flow direction.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how that would help in my case.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish what you want, but the idea here is to allow the FlowLayoutPanel to automatically rearrange the control layout as you show and hide certain controls.

Comment: Oh, so I would put both fields in the FlowLayoutPanel in different positions, and that would later be automatically moved to the right position?

Comment: Exactly. The FlowLayoutPanel keeps the visible controls together eliminating the empty spaces that your hidden controls would otherwise leave behind.

Answer (score 0):

You could just place them one on top of the other as you suggested. You said you did not want to do this because it would make selecting the properties of the controls difficult.

You can select a control from the combobox drop down menu on the properties section of Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: I think that would be bad programming style

Answer (score 0):

You should create two Different Panels and Add Objects based on the Requirement. After Put visible and Hide Code in the Check Box Checked Event.
Try Panels it Will Work.
You can Simple Move Panel Along with all you objects which make it super Easy.